# is it possible to create npm package for SailsJs project?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

is there any way to create **NPM** package for **SailsJs** models, controllers and config files.

Answer (score 1):

If you created project locally and installed all packages with

```
npm install PACKAGENAME --save
```

it added it to package.json which is your node.js config file. There are all dependencies. Only missing part is your code now. It should be in repository. You can modify package.json to include download it also with when you execute 'npm install'. Just add:

```
"repository" :
  { "type" : "git"
  , "url" : "https://github.com/npm/npm.git"
  }
```

To read more about package.json [click here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

Later you just need to upload your package.json to server and execute npm install.

Comment: I want to create custom NPM package for sails models and controllers.

Comment: You want to publish your project as npm module? Read documentation: [Publishing npm packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages). But only API layer is not a complete module without tests, assets, views & config. Sails are part of dependencies in package.json. **Remember not to add any private keys into repository!!!**

Comment: Yes I want to publish my project as npm.
i found solution for that i used **sails-util-mvcsloader**  and cutom hook for loading model,controllers,services,config and policies. Thank you for your time. :)